# Disable type providers in project

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013, type-providers, f#-3.1

I am developing a Type Provider.
I have a Test-Project where I have enabled the use of the type provider (by clicking "Enable" in the confirmation box that appears when you first add a reference to a type provider assembly).

Now I want to test the provider infrastructure without having to re-open a separate Visual studio instance just to be able to compile the type provider library. Is there a way to disable the use of the type provider in a project once it's been allowed?

I tried removing and re-adding the reference to the library containing the type provider and looking for some setting in the .fsproj file. To no avail...

Comment: use f# interactive for testing

Comment: I do, as much as possible. But dealing with exceptions is easier in Visual Studio.